# Custom Error Messages with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling, mongoose

So according to the mongoose [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), you are supposed to be able to set a custom error message in the schema like so:

```
 var breakfastSchema = new Schema({
  eggs: {
    type: Number,
    min: [6, 'Too few eggs'],
    max: 12
  },
  bacon: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Why no bacon?']
  }
});
```

So I wanted to do something similar:

```
var emailVerificationTokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   email: {type: String, required: true, unique: [true, "email must be unique"]},
   token: {type: String, required: true},
   createdAt: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: '4h'}
});
```

The idea being that when you attempt to save one of these tokens, and there is already a conflicting one it'll pump out an error message that says "email must be unique".

However when I do something like this (where I save a token with the same email):

```
verificationToken.save( function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I keep getting this:

```
'E11000 duplicate key error: index ___.emailVerificationToken.$email_1 dup key: { : "_____@wdad.com
```

Any thoughts? Is unique parameter not supported for custom messages? Is this a viable way of going about things?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Is unique parameter not supported for custom messages?

Uniqueness in Mongoose is not a validation parameter (like `required`); it tells Mongoose to create a unique index in MongoDB for that field.

The uniqueness constraint is handled entirely in the MongoDB server. When you add a document with a duplicate key, the MongoDB server will return the error that you are showing (`E11000...`).

You have to handle these errors yourself if you want to create custom error messages. The [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#error-handling-middleware) (*"Error Handling Middleware"*) provides you with an example on how to create custom error handling:

```
emailVerificationTokenSchema.post('save', function(error, doc, next) {
  if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
    next(new Error('email must be unique'));
  } else {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

(although this doesn't provide you with the specific field for which the uniqueness constraint failed)

Comment: your answers are  very accurate like always. if i may ask you please about the difference between [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query)  and [Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Model),im seeing both of them have many methods in common for instance `Model.deleteMany()` and `Query.prototype.deleteMany()`.

Comment: @Alexander I'm pretty sure that `Model.deleteMany` creates (and returns) a `Query` instance on which it calls `Query.prototype.deleteMany`. That query instance represents a "delete many" operation.

Comment: Just for update, now Mongoose uses "MongoServerError" as error.name instead of "MongoError"

Comment: Now we need `MongoServerError` instead of `MongoError`.

Answer (score 14):

It is not directly possible as you tried it but you may want to have a look at [mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator) which allows for custom error message if uniqueness would be violated.

In particular the section about [custom errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator#custom-error-messages) should be of interest to you.

To get your desired

> "email must be unique"

it would look similar to this

```
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
...
emailVerificationTokenSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: '{PATH} must be unique' });
```

Comment: This plugin is just what I was looking for!

Comment: I followed your link and I am trying to use the custom error message. I don't want to change only the message part (like in your example) but the whole response. 
So I am running : uniqueValidator.defaults.message = 'Error, expected {PATH} to be unique.' and then : userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator); but it's throwing error. Would you know why ?

Answer (score 5):

```
verificationToken.save( function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
          message: (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000) ? 'Email already exists !' : errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    }
    else {
      return console.log('No Error');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message that comes for unique values from the Schema is truly not human friendly.
This disturbed me a lot but when i saw the remaining keys in the error object, I was able to device this.

In returning the error message,

```
 document.save().then(() => {
        return res.status(201).json({
          statusText: "created",
          message: "document created successfully",
          data: brand,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {

        // Set custom error for unique keys
        let errMsg;
        if (error.code == 11000) {
          errMsg = Object.keys(error.keyValue)[0] + " already exists.";
        } else {
          errMsg = error.message;
        }
        res.status(400).json({ statusText: "Bad Request", message: errMsg });
      });
```

Comment: This is very useful if you have multiple unique keys in your Schema.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all answers, I've figured out my problem.

My schema is like that.

```
var User = new Schema({
  username: {type: String, required: [true, "Username is required"], unique: true},
  email: {type: String, required: [true, "Email is required"], unique: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true, unique: false},
});
```

I recommend to use like a function.

You can use like this;

```
User.post("save", function (error, doc, next) {

  if (error.keyValue.email != null && error.name === "MongoError" && error.code === 11000) {

    console.log("Email must be unique");
  } else if (error.keyValue.username != null && error.name === "MongoError" && error.code === 11000) {
    console.log("Username must be unique");
  } else {
    console.log("not found any idea, search for another reasons");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated version for Mongoose 5.x.x

```
MySchema.post('save', function (error, doc, next) {
    if (err.name === 'BulkWriteError' && error.code === 11000) 
        next(new Error('This item already exists, please try again'));
    else next(error);
});
```

Comment: You are right, but the first part of the conditional is unecesary. ` if (error.code === 11000) ` is enough...

Answer (score 2):

Just apply a middleware.

```
recordingSchema.post('save', function (error, _, next) {
    next( error.code === 11000 
      ?   new Error('This item field already exist')
      :   error)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add a custom async validator. for example:

```
 {
      validator: (value) => {
        return UserModel.findOne({ email: value })
          .then(user => Promise.resolve(user == null))
          .catch(error => Promise.reject(false));
      },
      message: "User with this email already exists"
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated mongoose version 5.x.x has support for this specific requirement.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#error-handling-middleware

You can add a post method for the schema and do as per the following:
// After saving the user, if user is duplicated, return error

```
userSchema.post('save', function(error: any, doc: any, next: any) {
  if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
    next(new Error('user_exists'));
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle it:

```
schema.post('save', function (error, doc, next) {
    let errorMessage

    // map with all unique items you defined in your schema 
    const errorsMap = {
        email: 'your message for existing email',
        otherUniqueItem: 'your message for existing item',
    }

    if (error.code === 11000) {
        errorMessage = Object
            .keys(error.keyValue)
            .map(key => errorMap[key])
            .join(', ')
    } else {
        errorMessage = error.message
    }

    if (errorMessage) next(new Error(errorMessage))
    else next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since unique is not a validator, there isn't a way to have a custom error in your schema for this scenario. However, another way to check for unique-ness is with the exists() method. For example:

```
const User = require('/path/to/model')

app.post('/route-name', async (req, res) => {
  // destructure the request body 
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  
  // Assuming you have an email property in your user model, we check if the email in the request body exists in the database
  // This can take multiple fields as well.
  const exists = await User.exists({ email: email });
  if (exists) return res.json({ error: 'email exists' });
  
  // rest of your logic if email doesn't exist
});
```