# Is there a pre/post hook that fires both on save and update?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have eg.

```
schema.pre('save', (next) => {
  console.log('save fired');
  next();
});
```

I assumed "save" would fire on all `schema.update()` and `schema.create()` events, as both technically "save" things.

For example, actions that modify a value that is `unique: true` in the schema, need to check if the new value doesn't throw a `DuplicateKey` (11000) error and throw their own error.

Is there a cleaner way than:

```
const createUpdateCommon = (next) => {/*check if thrown DuplicateKey error*/}

schema.pre('save', createUpdateCommon);
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', createUpdateCommon);
```

Also isn't there any pre hook that handles "any update" rather than having to specify findOne, findMany etc.?

Answer (score 1):

> Also isn't there any pre hook that handles "any update" rather than having to specify findOne, findMany etc.?

No. You need to provide each one manually.

> For example, actions that modify a value that is unique: true in the schema, need to check if the new value doesn't throw a DuplicateKey (11000) error and throw their own error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38946126/10706046 - you need to create a hook for each operation.

> I assumed "save" would fire on all schema.update() and schema.create() events, as both technically "save" things.

No. These are two separate operations in MongoDB. You'd need to create a hook for `create` and `findOneAndUpdate`.

On a side note, my problem here is that I was implementing validation for creating and update in `createUpdateCommon(incomingData)`.

I was checking if the incoming data (on create or update) wasn't eg referring to a countryId that didn't exist.

So in `createUpdateCommon` I had stuff like `city.findOne(incomingData.city)`.

**Do not use hooks for this. Use schema validators instead**
Like so:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  city: {
    type: String, //probably use ObjectID instead
    validator: (value) => !!cityModel.findOne(value.city) //returns true if finds a city
  }
}
```