# Mongoose: E11000 duplicate key change the type of return message in case of error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The following message is returned to me: `E11000 duplicate key error collection ...`, when one of the attributes that is specified as `unique: true`, it would be possible to modify this error message with a custom one for example:

```
{error: '11000', field: 'name of the field giving the problem'}
```

Comment: This is how you can customize the duplication error message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67021682/9894200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uniqueness in `mongoose` is not a `validation` parameter, so you can't create custom error message for these fields, it is only to create `uniqueness index` in DB.

What you can do is, create a [Error Handling middleware in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#error-handling-middleware), and intercept `11000` errors, and send a `custom error message` in `response`.

**From Mongoose documentation**

> ```
> // Handler **must** take 3 parameters: the error that occurred, the document
> // in question, and the `next()` function
> schema.post('save', function(error, doc, next) {
>   if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
>     next(new Error('There was a duplicate key error'));
>   } else {
>     next();
>   }
> });
> ```

Note: This allows you to catch 11000 duplication key error, but it doesn't tell you which field caused thee problem.

Comment: Some things:
- I can also use it in: `schema.pre ('save', function (next) {`
- with `error.message` I access the error message that is returned to me normally: `E11000 duplicate key error collection: ... `

Comment: You could use such a thing in case: `message.split(" ").map((el, key, array) => el.includes("index:") && array[key + 1]).filter(Boolean)[0].replace(/\_\d+/g, "")`

Comment: I pointed you in a direction how you can acheive it, you can modify it to work as per your needs